# findOneAndUpdate method returning before resolving

Tags: mongoose

The method is returning undefined. I.g., finishing before the `findOneAndUpdate` resolves.

```
exports.updateMovie = async (movie) => {
    try {
        return await Movie.findOneAndUpdate({_id: movie._id}, movie, {upsert: true, new: true}, (err, result) => {
            return result;
        });
    } catch(err) {
        return err;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 13):

As the [findOneAndUpdate doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) says, the method without a `callback` returns a `Query` which has to be executed. So to make the method work it should look like:

```js
exports.updateMovie = async (movie) => {
    try {
        return await Movie.findOneAndUpdate({_id: movie._id}, movie, {upsert: true, new: true}).exec();
    } catch(err) {
        return err;
    }
};
```